# Get Cell value from WPF Datagrid (in vb)

Tags: wpf, vb.net, wpfdatagrid

Hi I am converting a old vb.net program to WPF and am having trouble. I imported some data to a datatable and dumped that into a datagrid. I now need to go row by row and extract the cell values and use them to update the appropriate database record.

This was working in my old program using:

```
For i = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1

cellvalue = Me.datagrid.Items(i).Cells(8).Value).ToString

(insert to database) etc

next
```

I been searching around and apparently its not as simple in WPF. But all the working examples i can find are all in C# which I am not that famillar with and cant seem to convert to work. So if someone can provide me some code (in vb) that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you know [this converter](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/)?

Comment: @HB: He's converting WinForms to WPF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've already got a DataTable that contains your data, it is pretty easy to work with that:

```
Dim dt As New System.Data.DataTable
'...Load your data into DataTable

For Each rw As System.Data.DataRow In dt.Rows
   cellValue = rw(8).ToString
   '...insert to database
Next
```

Comment: yes but i may have changed the data in the datagrid before importing it :(

Comment: If you have bound your DataTable as the ItemsSource of your DataGrid, then when you update the DataGrid, the DataTable is also updated.  In WPF it is normally better to work with the underlying data objects rather than directly with the controls on the UI.

Comment: oh I wasnt sure                                                   well that changes things - anyhoo I found a different way 2 go     thanks for the assistance

Comment: ahh! it wont let me answer myself - the kudos are all yours!

Comment: Actually turns out I had the answer in my old code for a "clickevent" on a windows forms datagrid:---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- For Each item As DataRowView In datagrid.Items -------------------------------------------------------------------------------cellvalue = item.Item("ColumnName") ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------(insert to database) etc ---------------------------------------------------next

Answer (score 0):

```
For Each item As DataRowView In datagrid.Items    
cellvalue = item.Item("ColumnName") 
(insert to database) 
next
```